# controls loosing style after postback in Juice UI dialog with update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, postback, juice-ui

I've added a Button to an updatepanel which is inside a juiceUI dialog div.
The dialog is shown by clicking a hyperlink (see code). This works.
After the successfull postback via the Button-Click event, all controls are loosing their styles (using Fresh-Squeezed). I can't find the reason for that.
Note:I want to generate all controls in the code-behind.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager man = new ScriptManager();
    man.SupportsPartialRendering = true;

    this.Form.Controls.Add(man);

    HyperLink lnkOpen = new HyperLink(); lnkOpen.ID = "lnkOpen"; lnkOpen.Text = "open Dialog"; lnkOpen.CssClass = "open-dialog";
    this.Form.Controls.Add(lnkOpen);

    Juice.Dialog jDialog = new Dialog(); jDialog.ID = "jdialog";
    jDialog.Modal = true;
    jDialog.TargetControlID = "dialogItSelf";
    jDialog.AutoOpen = false;
    this.Form.Controls.Add(jDialog);

    UpdatePanel updPanel1 = new UpdatePanel(); updPanel1.ID = "upd1";        
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button buttonOK = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button(); buttonOK.ID = "button";
    buttonOK.Click += new EventHandler(buttonOK_Click);        
    updPanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(buttonOK);

    Panel basicDialog = new Panel(); basicDialog.ID = "dialogItSelf"; basicDialog.CssClass = "basic-dialog";

    basicDialog.Controls.Add(updPanel1);

    this.Form.Controls.Add(basicDialog);

    this.Form.Controls.Add(
        new LiteralControl("<script>$( \".open-dialog\" ).click( function ( e ) {" +
    "e.preventDefault();" +
    "$( \".basic-dialog\" ).dialog( \"open\" );" +
        "});</script>")
        );
}

void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button).Text = "clicked";
}
```